# Format.js will only render a partial that contains a single line

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Rails 3.2.1: I have the following div that calls a partial

```
<div id="weighin">
<%= render :partial => "my_weight/weighin" %>
</div>
```

The partial contains a form that posts ajax (ie has :remote => true) to a controller with:

```
respond_to do |format| 
   format.js
end
```

The .js.erb file has a single line:

```
$("#weighin").html("<%= render :partial => "my_weight/weighin1" %>");
```

The _weighin1.html.erb partial file has a single line:

```
<p><%= @my_weight[1].weight %></p>
```

This works, in that the original div is replaced with the value of the @my_weight field - so the fundamental structure is all working ok

However, Rails will not handle any more code in the partial - if I add so much as a carriage return to the end of that one line, the server log confirms all ok, but no script gets run on the page - ie nothing changes.

The same happens if I try to put more html in the partial, but put it all in a single line - this doesnt run either.

How can I output more than a single short statement in a partial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I figured this out:

```
$("#weighin").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "my_weight/weighin1") %>");
```

escape_javascript is essential

What is confusing is that, depending on what is in the html() you are sending, this will sometimes work without escape_javascript, leading one to a false conclusion... :-)